# How do I identify sequences of values in a boolean array?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, boolean

I have a long boolean array:

```
bool_array = [ True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False ]
```

I need to figure out where the values flips, i.e., the addresses where sequences of `True` and `False` begin. In this particular case, I would want to get

```
index = [0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26]
```

Is there an easy way to do without manually looping to check every ith element with the (i+1)th?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a more efficient approach for large datasets, in python 3.X you can use [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and  [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function from `itertools` module.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate, groupby
>>> [0] + list(accumulate(sum(1 for _ in g) for _,g in groupby(bool_array)))
[0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26]
```

---

The logic behind the code:

This code, categorizes the sequential duplicate items using `groupby()` function, then loops over the iterator returned by `groupby()` which is contains pairs of keys (that we escaped it using under line instead of a throw away variable) and these categorized iterators.

```
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby(bool_array)]
[[True, True, True, True, True], [False, False, False, False, False], [True, True, True], [False, False], [True, True, True, True], [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

So all we need is calculating the length of these iterators and sum each length with its previous length, in order to get the index of first item which is exactly where the item is changed, that is exactly what that `accumulate()` function is for.

In Numpy you can use the following approach:

```
In [19]: np.where(arr[1:] - arr[:-1])[0] + 1
Out[19]: array([ 5, 10, 13, 15, 19])
# With leading and trailing indices
In [22]: np.concatenate(([0], np.where(arr[1:] - arr[:-1])[0] + 1, [arr.size]))
Out[22]: array([ 0,  5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26])
```

Comment: I'd say the intent of this code is fairly opaque, even to fairly skilled people, unfortunately. `itertools` is awesome, but it's almost a language on its own.

Answer (score 15):

This will tell you where:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.argwhere(np.diff(bool_array)).squeeze()
array([ 4,  9, 12, 14, 18])
```

---

`np.diff` calculates the difference between each element and the next.  For booleans, it essentially interprets the values as integers (0: False, non-zero: True), so differences appear as +1 or -1 values, which then get mapped back to booleans (True when there is a change).

The `np.argwhere` function then tells you where the values are True --- which are now the changes.

Comment: Cool. This was what I was looking for. However, I marked the `accumulate` answer as correct as it was faster for a large array.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) you can do

```
>>> [i for i,(m,n) in enumerate(zip(bool_array[:-1],bool_array[1:])) if m!=n]
[4, 9, 12, 14, 18]
```

Now that you have `[4, 9, 12, 14, 18]`, you can

```
>>> [0]+[i+1 for i in [4, 9, 12, 14, 18]]+[len(bool_array)]
[0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26]
```

To achieve your output.

---

The logic behind the code:

- `zip` takes in two iterators and returns a sequence of two elements. We pass the same list for both iterators starting from the first element and one starting from the second. Hence we get a list of adjacent numbers
- `enumerate` gives you a sequence of indexes and the value of the iterator.
- Now we wrap it in a list comprehension. If the zipped values are not the same, we return the index

---

Another  single step procedure is

```
>>> [i for i,(m,n) in enumerate(zip([2]+bool_array,bool_array+[2])) if m!=n]
[0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26]
```

Here we are deliberately introducing `[2]` into the list, This is because the first and the last values will always be different (as `[2]` is never present in the list). Hence we will get those indexes directly.

Comment: fast for smaller lists.

Comment: `answer++`: I'm pleased to see an answer that doesn't rely on `itertools` and / or `numpy`.

Comment: You can skip the second step if you add a value to the front, instead of dropping one.

Comment: @alexis Yep, `[i for i,(m,n) in enumerate(zip([2]+bool_array,bool_array+[2])) if m!=n]` will work better. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw your comment now. I thought `2` was the first value. Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can use and increment a variable within a list comprehension. Coupled with `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

# bool_array = [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
total = 0
[total := total + len(list(gp)) for _, gp in groupby(bool_array)]
# [5, 10, 13, 15, 19, 26]
```

This:

- Initializes a variable `total` to `0` which symbolizes the cumulative sum
- Groups consecutive items with `groupby` (consecutive `True` will be grouped together, same goes for consecutive `False`)
- For each series of grouped booleans, this both:

  - increments `total` with the current length of the series of booleans (`total := total + len(list(gp))`) via an **assignment expression**
  - and at the same time, maps the consecutive series to the new value of `total`

<sub>Of course to make this start with `0`, you can always plug `[0]` to the front of the list.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas shift to find where value != the next.

```
import pandas as pd
bool_array = [ True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False ]
bools = pd.Series(bool_array)
flips = bools != bools.shift(1)
flips[flips].index
```

Int64Index([0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19], dtype='int64')

or as a list

```
list(flips[flips].index)
```

[0, 5, 10, 13, 15, 19]