# Finding False-True transitions in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array:

```
x = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False])
```

How do I find the number of times the values transitions from False to True?
For the above example, the answer would be 2. I *don't* want to include transitions from True to False in the count.

From the answers to [How do I identify sequences of values in a boolean array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894822/how-do-i-identify-sequences-of-values-in-a-boolean-array), the following produces the indices at which the values are about to change, which is not what I want as this includes True-False transitions.

```
np.argwhere(np.diff(x)).squeeze()
# [0 2 7 8]
```

I know that this can be done by looping through the array, however I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get one-off slices - `x[:-1]` (starting from the first elem and ending in second last elem) and `x[1:]` (starting from the second elem and going on until the end), then look for the first slice being lesser than the second one, i.e. catch the pattern of `[False, True]`  and finally get the count with `ndarray.sum()` or `np.count_nonzero()` -

```
(x[:-1] < x[1:]).sum()
np.count_nonzero(x[:-1] < x[1:])
```

Another way would be to look for the first slice being `False` and the second one as `True`, the idea again being to  catch that pattern of `[False, True]` -

```
(~x[:-1] & x[1:]).sum()
np.count_nonzero(~x[:-1] & x[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

I kind of like to use numpy method "roll" for this kind of problems...
"roll" rotates the array to left some step length : (-1,-2,...) or to right (1,2,...)

```
import numpy as np
np.roll(x,-1)
```

...this will give x but shifted one step to the left:

```
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], 
dtype=bool)
```

A False followed by a True can then be expressed as:

```
~x & np.roll(x,-1)

array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], 
dtype=bool)
```