# Get beginning and end of range in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose I have a signal, say, a sine wave:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x/10)
```

When I plot this, I want to highlight in red the regions where the value of `y` is above a certain threshold, e.g. 0.7. I thought of doing something like this

```
region = [i for i, e in enumerate(y) if e >= 0.7]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

k = region [0]
for i in region:
    if i-k == 1:
       ax.axvspan(k, i+1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)
    k = i

plt.show()
```

The  `+1` is added because I want to "include" the last point in the highlighted region.

However, this generates overlapping `axvspan`s, which means that the first and last one will be "lighter" (because I'm using `alpha = 0.2`), as in the figure:
[image: Plot]

Is there another (possibly simpler) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to apply a mask to `y` to find where the values are above your threshold. You then need to find the first and last occurrence where the values of the mask are `True`. This can be done by finding `True-False` and `False-True` transitions by using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750593/finding-false-true-transitions-in-a-numpy-array):

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x/10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

mask = y >= 0.7

first_vals = np.argwhere((~mask[:-1] & mask[1:]))  # Look for False-True transitions
last_vals = np.argwhere((mask[:-1] & ~mask[1:])) + 1  # Look for True-False transitions

for start, stop in zip(first_vals, last_vals):
    ax.axvspan(start, stop, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Introducing a second condition means you will have to use `numpy.logical_or`. Some extra checks might have to be introduced if the first value of the mask is `True`:

```
mask = np.logical_or(y>0.7, y==0)

if mask[0]:
    first_vals = np.argwhere((~mask[:-1] & mask[1:]))  # Look for False-True transitions
    last_vals = np.argwhere((mask[:-1] & ~mask[1:])) + 1 # Look for True-False transitions
    first_vals = np.insert(first_vals, 0, 0, axis=0)

for start, stop in zip(first_vals, last_vals):
    ax.axvspan(start, stop, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: If you compare the x-values of the right hand edge of your figure and the OP's figure, you will see that you are missing a slice (thin) on the right hand side of both the patches. This is exactly what the OP gets if he/she replaces `ax.axvspan(k, i+1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)` by `ax.axvspan(k, i, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)`. Perhaps you should use `>=0.7`

Comment: @DavidG this seems to be the right way. I now want to add another region, but if I write `mask = (y >= 0.7) or (y == 0)` I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: @Enzo I've updated the answer, see if that helps you?

Comment: @DavidG that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Though in your answer only one region with a zero is found, but I assume that's due to the x not being exactly `n*pi`, hence the y won't be exactly zero, right?

Comment: @Enzo Yep that's right, the closest y values of the second "near zero" region are 0.02 and then -0.07 so it didn't catch them. You would probably have to specify some boundaries to get values close to zero

Comment: @DavidG That's fine, for my purposes I only need exact zeroes. That was just my curiosity. Thank you again.